# last child with element inside

Tags: css, extjs, radio-button, css-selectors

I think this is impossible :-(

Using CSS, I need to select the last `label` in the list of paragraphs, which is inside of a `span`.

```
<div>
    <p>
        <span>
            <label>no good, because not the last</label>
        </span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>
            <label>good</label> <!-- This one should be selected -->
        </span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>no good, because is not inside of a span</label>
    </p>
</div>
```

Virtually the selector would be something like this:

```
div (p > span):last-child label {
    background: red;
}
```

But I don't think CSS understands parenthesis (yet).

The reason for this is that ExtJS (Sencha) puts radio buttons in nested containers. The visibility of buttons is declared in the inner containers (that would be the `span` tags in the example above). I want to round corners of the last VISIBLE label, thus I need to find the last outer container that has an inner container declaring it's visibility.

Perhaps there is a different workaround for this? As a last resort, I'd accept a JS solution, as long as it's based on native ExtJS components/elements traversing syntax, rather than jQuery.

Please ask for more detail if needed.

Comment: In short,, which nth element you want to select?

Comment: It can't be nth. It has to be the last visible - in this particular case the last containing another element.

Comment: You want to select this -> `<p><span>good</span></p>`

Comment: I'm sorry, yes. I thought it was clear.

Comment: Your modified question is very different. No need for `:has` anymore. But the main problem still is: There is no `:last` selector in CSS.

Comment: @LinusCaldwell It is not that much different. Yes you do need a ":has" because you have to check whether it has a `span` or not. And you are wrong ":last-child" is a valid CSS selector. The problem here is the parenthesis I think.

Comment: 1. No, you don't need a `:has` selector because `p > span > label` cannot select a `<label/>` that is not inside a `<span/>`. 2. I didn't say `:last-child` is invalid, i said there is no `:last` selector which is something completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will (maybe, depends on if the selector will be in the final spec) partly be possible with [CSS 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject):

```
!p > span {
    background: red;
}
```

But this will select all `<p/>` that have a `<span/>` inside, not only the last one. CSS currently does not know a `:last` selector, and as far as I can see even with CSS 4 this won't be implemented<sup>1</sup>.

**So the summary is**: Currently there is no way to do this in pure CSS.

---

Currently your only option is to use JavaScript. A sample in jQuery would be:

```
$('p:has(span)').last().css({ 'background': 'red' });
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Geyuk/).

Or, as you mentioned in your comment, with extjs:

```
Ext.select('p:has(span):last').setStyle('background', 'red');
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vYmWX/).

---

### Answer to your updated question

Your new example does not need a parent selector anymore. The **partly** working CSS would be

```
div > p > span > label {
    background: red;
}
```

But still: **There is no `:last` selector in CSS**<sup>1</sup>. Updating the above JavaScript samples:

[jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/a8KQV/):

```
$('div > p > span > label').last().css({ 'background': 'red' });
```

[extJS](http://jsfiddle.net/MSwff/):

```
Ext.select('div > p > span > label:last').setStyle('background', 'red');
```

---

<sup>1 About the `:last` selector:</sup>

To make it more clear: `:last-child` selects the last child inside an element in the dom, whatever it is. It is no sub query. So, even if your parenthesis version would be implemented, `:last-child` would select nothing because the really last element is not part of the query. You would need a `:last` selector like in some JavaScript libraries which selects the last item of the resultset, so it's a sub query. This is a completely different selector and will not be part of CSS soon.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I figured I could do it using jQuery. But I'm ExtJS right now. Never heard of CSS4 - this is exciting!

Comment: @Geo You need to use this solution, as of now there's no work around for this :)

Comment: That site is horribly out of date. The subject selector does not use that syntax anymore, and in fact, it may not even be usable in CSS once Selectors 4 is implemented. See my comments under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector/1014958#1014958

Comment: @BoltClock, thank you! Updated my answer. Maybe you know if the `:nth-last-match()` selector will work this way.

Comment: No, `:nth-last-match()` operates based on siblings as well, and its use of combinators is also not allowed in CSS. In short, this will still not be doable in CSS, unfortunately...

Comment: Ended up using JS. Thank you!